# Adding values in two data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables, and one has a subset of rows/columns of another. I'd like to add values of the smaller data.table to the values of the larger one:

```
DT1 <- as.data.table(matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 3), nrow=2, ncol=2, 
       dimnames=list(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b"))), keep=T)
DT2 <- as.data.table(matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3), nrow=3, ncol=3, 
       dimnames=list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"))), keep=T)

DT1
#   rn a b
#1:  a 0 2
#2:  b 1 3
DT2
#   rn a b c
#1:  a 0 2 1
#2:  b 0 2 0
#3:  c 1 1 3
```

I'd like to add DT1 to DT2 so that I get

```
#   rn a b c
#1:  a 0 4 1
#2:  b 1 5 0
#3:  c 1 1 3
```

I know I can overwrite values of DT2 with DT1 very easily:

```
DT2[DT1, names(DT1) := DT1, on="rn"]
```

I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
DT2[DT1, names(DT1) := DT1 + .SD, on="rn"]
```

...but it doesn't. There's probably some simple variation on this that would work, though, right?

Comment: Non-`data.table` solutions to this same problem can be found here: [How to merge and sum two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468502/how-to-merge-and-sum-two-data-frames)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer Richard's way, but here's an alternative that looks more like the OP's initial idea:

```
vs = setdiff(names(DT1),"rn")
DT2[DT1, (vs) := {
  x.SD = mget(vs) 
  i.SD = mget(paste0("i.",vs)) 
  Map("+", x.SD, i.SD)
}, on="rn", by=.EACHI]
#    rn a b c
# 1:  a 0 4 1
# 2:  b 1 5 0
# 3:  c 1 1 3
```

Comment: While this is maybe a bit more convoluted, it's significantly faster than Richard's answer -- thanks!

Comment: Huh. I ran both on a small data.table (1.3M x 70) and Rich's was 70 times faster!  1.5 seconds against 102 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `rbindlist()` to bring the two together, then sum the values based on `rn`

```
rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), fill=TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]
#    rn a b c
# 1:  a 0 4 1
# 2:  b 1 5 0
# 3:  c 1 1 3
```